# Implement Demographic and interest report in Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics

I have build an android Hybrid App with Apache corodova. I have also add danwilson plugin for google analytics but I am unable to get Demographic and Interest report for my corodova application.
Danwilson plugin link
[Danwilson plugin link](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin)